# QVector<QVector<>> size

Tags: c++, qt

I want to know the number of total elements in an object of `QVector<QVector<type>>`, say `myobject`. One way to do this is to set a for-loop as follows:

```
int siz;
QVector<type> temp;
for(int i=0; i<myobject.size(); i++)
{
    temp = myobject[i];
   for(int j=0; j<temp.size(); j++)
   {
     siz += temp.size();
   }
}
```

Although workable, this way I feel is pretty cumbersome. Is there any more efficient or neater alternatives to estimate the size of `QVector<QVector<type>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic used in your posted code is incorrect.

```
temp = myobject[i];
for(int j=0; j<temp.size(); j++)
{
  siz += temp.size();
}
```

adds the size of `temp` to `siz` too many times. It needs to added to `siz` only once.

You need:

```
int siz = 0;
for(int i=0; i<myobject.size(); i++)
{
   siz += myobject.at(i).size();
}
```

As pointed out by @Mike, use of `myobject[i]` may result in a deep copy. For read-only access, use `myobject.at(i)`.

From [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#details):

> `at()` can be faster than `operator[]()`, because it never causes a deep copy to occur.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [the answer by R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193410/2666212), I just want to point out that you are incurring a gratuitous copy of the inner `QVector` object in every iteration of the outer loop. You might want to get a const reference to the inner vector instead.

Another way of doing this would be using `std::accumulate` algorithm i.e.:

```
int wholeSize = std::accumulate(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), 0,
                                [](int currentSize, const QVector<type> &v) {
                                  return currentSize + v.size();
                                });
```